# how can I scrape web special words in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want a web page scrape of special words and I want if the 'org' is 'England' give me id='name' and 'England'
my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://however.org/plus')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all(id={'name', 'org'})

for item in res:
    print(item.text.strip())
```

so, my output will be this:

```
General English: Intermediate <====== (name)
american   <======= (org)
General English: Elementary
England    <=======
General English: Intermediate Plus
England
General English: Beginner
american
TOEFL iBT: Listening and Speaking
England
TOEFL iBT: Reading
american
Grammar for IELTS
american
```

but I want just if org is England give me name and don't want american org and that name
I want this output;

```
General English: Elementary
England 
General English: Intermediate Plus
England
TOEFL iBT: Listening and Speaking
England
```

how can I fix this? I want a print name with org if org is 'England'

Answer (score 0):

If all you're worried about is the output then this modification on the for loop should suffice:

```
for item in res:
   if 'england' in item.text.lower():
   #if 'england' == item.get('org').lower():
       print(item.get('name'), item.get('org'))
       #print('Name: ', item.get('name'), ', Org:', item.get('org'))
```

Comment: will I use them print output just England and don't print name                                                       I want the print name and below them org

Comment: Sorry, didn't got it at first, edited the answer accordingly. Check if the commented 'if' works for you. You can also add those strings to a data structure to work with them further in your script.

Comment: #print('Name: 'item.get('name'), ', Org:', item.get('org')) <===== syntax this is wrong!!!!

Comment: A comma between the first and second parameter of the 'print' function was missing, now is right.

Comment: None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None

Comment: will I print your code output this will be like this: none none